# MySQL queries timing out after 30 seconds

Tags: mysql, workbench

I am MySQL beginner and trying to get into MySQL world. Every time I run a long query in Workbench, it gets timed out at around 30 seconds with an error:

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

Why am I getting this error?